# How to see profile assigned to a user

Tags: oracle11g, profile

Let's say i have created a user as '**TEST_USER**' with some profile.

I want some **query** that will show what profile a user is **assigned** with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/network.1111/e16543/users.htm#i1009117):

```
select profile from dba_users where username = 'TEST_USER';
```